# Why Android system bottom navigation bar height may be 0?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation-bar

I'm using Compose and need the bottom nav panel size, to correctly calculate some properties. But the problem is that it doesn't matter what os version or device, I receive 0 for both the top and bottom system bars.

How I try to get this size:

```
LocalWindowInsets.current.navigationBars.bottom
```

It's possible, that you don't have this size if the bar has not been calculated, is not visible, or something like this. But I see the bar and it's active.

What can cause this issue and maybe there's another way to get this size?